# Android NDK module not compiling (MIPS and MIPS64 are no longer supported)

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm getting this output **on Mac** when I try to compile an Android module with native C++ code after update to latest NDK (android-ndk-r17-darwin).

```
CMake Error at /Users/user1/Library/Android/sdk/ndk- 
bundle/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake:312 (message):
Invalid Android ABI: armeabi.  (armeabi is no longer supported.  Use
armeabi-v7a.)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/Users/user1/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/share/cmake- 
3.6/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:98 (include) CMakeLists.txt
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error at /Users/user1/Library/Android/sdk/ndk- 
bundle/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake:312 (message):
Invalid Android ABI: mips.  (MIPS and MIPS64 are no longer 
supported.)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/Users/user1/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/share/cmake- 
3.6/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:98 (include)
CMakeLists.txt
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
CMake Error at /Users/user1/Library/Android/sdk/ndk- 
bundle/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake:312 (message):
Invalid Android ABI: mips64.  (MIPS and MIPS64 are no longer 
supported.)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/Users/user1/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/share/cmake- 
3.6/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:98 (include)
CMakeLists.txt
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I've already tried [this solution](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/issues/309) but didn't work. The only solution was to return to the previous NDK.

Project is working fine with the previous version of NDK (android-ndk-r16b-darwin)

Anyone facing the same problem?

Comment: NDK r17 doesn't support MIPS so you will have to remove it from your build files. AFAIK, you are allowed to upgrade apps at Play Store even if you remove support for an architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits

> Known Issue: If you are using Android Plugin for Gradle 3.0.1 or lower
>   with NDK r17 or higher, you may get the following error: Error:ABIs
>   [mips64, armeabi, mips] are not supported for platform. That's because
>   older versions of the plugin still include the unsupported ABIs by
>   default when you build per-ABI APKs. To resolve this issue, either
>   update to the latest version of the plugin, or, in your app's
>   build.gradle file, reset the plugin's default list of ABIs and include
>   only the supported ABIs you want, as shown below:

So or add this to your *build.gradle*:

```
defaultConfig {
    // some of your code here
    splits {
        abi {
            ...
            reset()
            include "x86", "armeabi-v7a", "armeabi-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
}
```

or just update to use the latest Gradle plugin.